# How is the lifecycle of an ELB or a CDI bean when injected into a singleton?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, cdi, lifecycle, ejb-3.1

I would like to inject some session beans into a singleton EJB and am not sure what their lifecycle would be in this case. All the information I have found mentions client requests (as in remote applications or servlet-type calls) but I have not been able to find what exactly constitutes such ‘clients’, ‘requests’, and ‘sessions’.

What would be the lifecycle of a SFSB or a SLSB when it is injected into a singleton EJB?

Considering that, as I understand, one instance of the singleton is always active, would the session beans that it instantiates remain always active as well?

Would a ‘client request’ to the session beans be their injection as an instance variable of the singleton or a call to one of their methods?

Would it make sense (is it possible? would it make a difference?) to inject a SLSB as a local variable inside a method (if the functionality of the SLSB is only used inside that method), as opposed to injecting it as an instance variable of the singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the lifecycle of a SFSB or a SLSB when it is injected
>   into a singleton EJB?

Your singleton bean might correspond to a single instance of SFSB or SLSB per variable, but it will be up to the container as usual. You only have the proxies at the singleton.

> Considering that, as I understand, one instance of the singleton is
>   always active, would the session beans that it instantiates remain
>   always active as well?

A SFSB might timeout if not used. Meanwhile an SLSB, once invoked, can stay at the container as long as the container allows.

> Would a ‘client request’ to the session beans be their injection as an
>   instance variable of the singleton or a call to one of their methods?

A client request may refer to the transfer of task responsibility during the injection of a SLSB/SFSB. A client request may also refer to a call to one of the methods of the SLSB/SFSB.

> Would it make sense (is it possible? would it make a difference?) to
>   inject a SLSB as a local variable inside a method (if the
>   functionality of the SLSB is only used inside that method), as opposed
>   to injecting it as an instance variable of the singleton class?

You can't inject a SLSB as local variable inside a method.